# angular.js two directives, second one does not execute

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have two directives defined in an angular.js module. The HTML element that is declared first executes its directive, but the second HTML element that uses the other directive does not execute it.

Given this HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="PlayersCtrl">
    <div primary text="{{primaryText}}"/>
    <div secondary text="{{secondaryText}}"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this angular.js code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function PlayersCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.primaryText = "Players";
    $scope.secondaryText = "the best player list";
}

myApp.directive('primary', function(){
  return {
    scope: {
      text: '@'
    },
    template: '<h1>{{text}}</h1>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      console.log('primary directive');
    }
  };
});

myApp.directive('secondary', function(){
  return {
    scope: {
      text: '@'
    },
    template: '<h3>{{text}}</h3>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      console.log('secondary directive');
    }
  };
});
```

The resulting HTML is only the "primary" directive, and the "secondary" directive does not render:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" class="ng-scope">
  <div ng-controller="PlayersCtrl" class="ng-scope">
    <div primary="" text="Players" class="ng-isolate-scope ng-scope">
      <h1 class="ng-binding">Players</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The console output verifies this as well, as only the "primary directive" text is output.

Then if I *switch* the order of the primary and secondary elements, the *secondary* directive is executed and the *primary* directive is not:

```
<!-- reversed elements -->
<div secondary text="{{secondaryText}}"/>
<div primary text="{{primaryText}}"/>

<!-- renders this HTML (secondary, no primary) -->
<div ng-app="myApp" class="ng-scope">
  <div ng-controller="PlayersCtrl" class="ng-scope">
    <div secondary="" text="the best player list" class="ng-isolate-scope ng-scope">
      <h3 class="ng-binding">the best player list</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why is this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The answer is transclusion.

Comment: Transclusion has nothing to do with this, it is a simple HTML syntax error.

Comment: After reading up on transclusion and using it in my directives, it worked and solved the problem. I don't know why. It didn't seem to make sense at the time either. I jumped the gun in any case.

Comment: Transclusion may have appeared to clear up the problem because it might have appended the `secondary` element to the `primary` one instead of them being siblings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`div`'s are not [void elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-elements) and require a closing tag.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="PlayersCtrl">
    <div primary text="{{primaryText}}"></div>
    <div secondary text="{{secondaryText}}"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/PHzIbnRySO3yKCFY2v1s?p=preview)

Comment: I ran into same problem, but it is resolved after I changed <my-directive/> to <my-directive></my-directive>, inspired by this answer.